# Map discrete value to color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create pcolor based on 4 discrete value 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to define 1 as black, 2 as red, 3 as yellow and 4 as green. does anyone know how to do it?

```
test = ([1,2,2,1,3],[1,1,1,1,4],[2,1,1,2,1])
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array(test)
plt.pcolor(dataset)
```

Thanks,

Comment: sounds like you want a dictionary that maps these discrete values to pcolor values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you want to use pcolor. [From the Matlab docs](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) (presumably the matplotlib pcolor does the same thing):

> The minimum and maximum elements of C are assigned the first and last colors in the colormap. Colors for the remaining elements in C are determined by a linear mapping from value to colormap element.

You could try `imshow` instead, and use a `dict` to map the colors you want:

```
colordict = {1:(0,0,0),2:(1,0,0),3:(1,1,0),4:(0,1,0)}
test = ([1,2,2,1,3],[1,1,1,1,4],[2,1,1,2,1])
test_rgb = [[colordict[i] for i in row] for row in test]
plt.imshow(test_rgb, interpolation = 'none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html), you can create colors like this

```
red = (1, 0, 0)    # This would be red
green = (0, 1, 0)  # this is green
```

So
    colors = ((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0))

would give you `colors[1]` red, and `colors[2]` green.

This program shows how pcolor works:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

def test_pcolor():
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('gnuplot')
    Z = np.empty((100, 100))
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            Z[y, x] = 0.0001 * x * y

    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    c = plt.pcolor(Z, cmap = cmap)

    plt.show()

def main():
    test_pcolor()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bottom left is 0.0, top right is 1.0. pcolor takes the actual colors from a gradient. I've used the gnuplot gradient here. So 0.0 is the color left of the gradient, 1.0 is the color at the right.

If you want particular colors, you can define your own gradient.  [This](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) is a nice tutorial on colormaps.

Comment: I modified my case a little bit to fit what exactly I want. In general I understand how the colors definition works, but I still dont know how to fit it in the pcolor statement.

Comment: Added a simple example to the reply.