# Map discrete value to color by type and position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I asked how to map discrete value to color yesterday and got the following useful answer.

[Map discrete value to color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585096/map-discrete-value-to-color)

I am trying to graph colors based on 4 discrete value 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to define 1 as black, 2 as red, 3 as yellow and 4 as green. does anyone know how to do it?

You could try `imshow` instead, and use a `dict` to map the colors you want:

```
colordict = {1:(0,0,0),2:(1,0,0),3:(1,1,0),4:(0,1,0)}
test = ([1,2,2,1,3],[1,1,1,1,4],[2,1,1,2,1])
test_rgb = [[colordict[i] for i in row] for row in test]
plt.imshow(test_rgb, interpolation = 'none')
```

[image]

However, there are some data attributes for the lists of values and I would like to show them in the graph as well. Two things in particulars are:

1. each list of color has a unique type, so the graph should show type for each horizontal color bar.
2. each list of color has a corresponding list of positions, which indicate the end position from last one (all of them start with 0 and end at 20)

`dict = {'Type': ['A', 'B','C'], 'ColorList': [[1,2,2,1,3],[1,1,1,1,4],[2,1,1,2]], 'Position': [[3,6,9,15,20], [2,10,13,16,20], [6, 10, 12, 20]]}`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

so, the graph should look like similar except the x and y axis change to indicate the position of the color and type of the list of colors.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need the `plt.annotate` function; eg, for the first square `plt.annotate ('black', xy = (0, 0), color = 'white')`

Regarding the rest of your code, you'd be better off using a subclass of `enum` (requires Python 3.0):

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
...     black = 1
...     red = 1
...     yellow = 2
...     green = 3
```

Possibly including something along the lines of:

```
...     def RGB (self):
...         return {1:(0, 0, 0), 2:(1, 0, 0), 3:(1, 1, 0), 4:(0, 1, 0)}[self.value]
```

Rewriting using a subclass of `Enum` and a list comprehension should make your code easier to work with.

PS: I think you're overriding the standard function `dict` with `dict = ...`